# TS flag for detecting possible undefined error with empty array

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I have the following scenario:

```
 const validateCartItem = (filteredItem: ICartItem[]) => {
    if (!filteredItem[0].quantity) return setExistCartQuantity(0);
    ...
  };
```

`filteredItem` here is either empty array or array of `ICartItem` (as seen above).  However,  the above code can result in an error due to the fact that `filteredItem` can equal `[ ]` and thus `filteredItem[0].quantity` is equivalent to `undefined.quantity` resulting in an error.

Is there not a `tsconfig.json` flag for telling TS to enforce check such as `filteredItem[0]?.quantity` to ensure that `filteredItem[0]` is not defined or to short circuit the whole value to `undefined` per usual?

I can't seem to find it if it does exist.

Comment: You're looking for [`--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) but people usually leave it off because it becomes annoying to do other common things (like a `for` loop with an index).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (or find a suitable dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes this does seem to be exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!